# Какая нотация используется при описании конструкций Python?

Tags: python

При чтении документации по языку Python на официальном сайте используется нотация, отличающаяся от стандартной нотации Бекуса-Нура и от расширенной нотации Вирта. Мне так кажется.

Может ли кто кинуть в меня ссылку на ее описание, и второе - объяснить почему не использовалась стандартная нотация. Ну например, фигурные скобки для указания повторяющихся элементов.

Вот пример описания оператора "def":

```
funcdef                   ::=  [decorators] "def" funcname"(" parameter_list] ")"
                               ["->" expression] ":" suite
decorators                ::=  decorator+
decorator                 ::=  "@" assignment_expression NEWLINE
parameter_list            ::=  defparameter ("," defparameter)* "," "/" ["," [parameter_list_no_posonly]]
                                 | parameter_list_no_posonly
parameter_list_no_posonly ::=  defparameter ("," defparameter)* ["," [parameter_list_starargs]]
                               | parameter_list_starargs
parameter_list_starargs   ::=  "*" [parameter] ("," defparameter)* ["," ["**" parameter [","]]]
                               | "**" parameter [","]
parameter                 ::=  identifier [":" expression]
defparameter              ::=  parameter ["=" expression]
funcname                  ::=  identifier
```

в стандарте должно было бы быть **<funcname>**, а не **funcname**.
Повторение задается фигурными скобками **{}**. А здесь - кажется -для повторения используется конструкция **()***.

[Ссылка](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) на приведенное  описание. Пункт 8.7

Вопрос задаю, поскольку студенты спрашивают: "А почему?"

Comment: Приведите примеры что ли какие-то и ссылки. Лазить всё гуглить чтобы понять, о чём вообще вопрос - как-то не очень )

Comment: я в тексте напмсал пример..

Comment: Ну, не словами я имел в виду, а куском доки проиллюстрировать с этими самыми скобками, для наглядности.

Comment: @CrazyElf готово!

Comment: Вот так лучше. Я вам один минус компенсировал своим плюсом за старание )  По сути не отвечу, но думаю так больше шансов у вопроса...

Answer (score 2):

В [первой главе](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/introduction.html#notation) документации есть описание нотации.

*Вольный перевод...*

В описаниях лексического анализа и синтаксиса используется *модифицированная нотация грамматики BNF*. Используется следующий стиль определения:

```
name      ::=  lc_letter (lc_letter | "_")*
lc_letter ::=  "a"..."z"
```

В первой строке говорится, что `name` - это `lc_letter`, за которым следует последовательность из нуля или более `lc_letter` и подчеркиваний. `lc_letter`, в свою очередь, представляет собой любой из одиночных символов от «`a`» до «`z`». *(Это правило по факту соблюдается для имён, определённых в лексических и грамматических правилах в этом документе.)*

Каждое правило начинается с имени *(которое описывает правило)* и `:: =`.
Вертикальная черта (`|`) используется для разделения альтернатив; это наименее связывающий оператор в этой нотации.
Звёздочка (`*`) означает ноль или более повторений предыдущего элемента;
аналогично, плюс (`+`) означает одно или несколько повторений,
а фраза, заключённая в квадратные скобки (`[]`), означает ноль или один повтор *(другими словами, заключённая фраза является необязательной)*.
Операторы `*` и `+` связываются настолько плотно, насколько это возможно;
круглые скобки используются для группировки.
Литералы заключаются в кавычки.
Пробел имеет значение только для разделения токенов.
Правила обычно записаны в одну строку; правила со многими альтернативами могут быть отформатированы в несколько строк, каждая строка после первой начинается с вертикальной черты.

В лексических определениях *(как в примере выше)* используются ещё два соглашения: Два литеральных символа, разделённые тремя точками, означают любой символ в данном (включительном) диапазоне символов ASCII. Фраза между угловыми скобками (`<...>`) даёт неформальное описание определяемого символа; например, это может быть использовано для описания понятия «управляющий символ», если необходимо.

Несмотря на то, что используемая нотация почти одна и та же, существует большая разница между значением лексического и синтаксического определений: лексическое определение работает с отдельными символами входного источника, в то время как определение синтаксиса работает с потоком токенов, генерируемых лексическим анализом. Все случаи использования BNF в следующей главе *(«Лексический анализ»)* являются лексическими определениями; в последующих главах используются синтаксические определения.

Comment: Собственно, статья в википедии есть про расширенную BNF https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%91%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0 может на неё ссылку дать там, где упоминание?

Comment: Благодарю И кто б сказал - зачем?

Comment: Ну и в расширенной повторение задаётся фигурными скобками. А тут не расширенная, а модифицированная. И зачем?

Comment: @CrazyElf Ну здесь всё же далеко не РБНФ (1996). Видимо потому, что Python зародился раньше (1989), но обычного BNF ему показалось мало.